# angularJs call multiple links

Tags: angularjs, iframe

If I want to call a link into iframe with angular Js, I do this:

in HTML

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{customUrl}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In script

```
$scope.customUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/ie06-rsfgio');
```

but what about if I want to make a ng-repeat with several iframes?

May I make something like this (obviously not this)?

```
$scope.videoList = [video: $scope.customUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/ie06-rsfgio'), 
video: $scope.customUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/ie06-rsfgio'), 
video: $scope.customUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/ie06-rsfgio')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try this: Works Well !!* http://plnkr.co/edit/zf2YDyesNZXWwMrygNG1?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat = "src in sources track by $index">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{getTrust(src)}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
```

**JS:**

```
  $scope.sources = ['https://www.youtube.com/embed/ie06-rsfgio',
        'https://www.youtube.com/embed/ie06-rsfgio',

    ];
    $scope.getTrust = function(src){
      return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
    };
```